# Falha no Deploy do Laravel 4 em hospedagem compartilhada

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, deploy

Estou querendo subir meu primeiro projeto com o framework Laravel 4 e estou com problema. Subi todos os arquivos do projeto FTP pois não há outra opção para serviço contratado. Subi os arquivos e criei um arquivo `.htaccess` que se encontra na imagem juntamente com mensagem de erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, ele não está achando os arquivos. Na sua última regra está public, não seria public_html? Verique os caminhos..

Answer (score 1):

Consegui achar a Solução para este problema na verdade era versão do php oferecida para hospedagem que era 5.2 e Laravel exige uma versão 5.3+ então vou me indicado este link: http://faq.hostgator.com.br/content/54/290/pt-br/habilitando-o-php-53-em-seu-site.html. Com isso consegui resolver meu problema

Comment: Não coloque "resolvido" no título da pergunta. Apenas dê um Ok na sua própria resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o ficheiro **autoload.php** não foi carregado para o ftp.
Esse ficheiro deveria estar dentro da pasta **bootstrap** que deverá estar ao mesmo nível da pasta **public**

O erro diz que o ficheiro **index.php** foi carregado, mas que depois falhou o carregamento do tal **autoload.php**, por isso parece que o php está a funcionar e o ficheiro **index.php** está a ser acedido correctamente.